# Only the slide of a new section to have a header

Tags: beamer

I want only the slide of a new section to have a header, another solution that would help me is to reduce the size,

and the first page to put the name of the project, name of the university I want to have it on the first slide

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Group 7} % Your name
\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 2}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following definition of the headline:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Group 7} % Your name
\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}
  {%
    \ifnum\thepage=\insertsectionstartpage
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}    
    \fi
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection1.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 1.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 2}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection2.2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection 2.2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A help more please, how can I put a blank page forward?

Comment: @x-rw I don't understand, where do you want a blank page?

Comment: the first page to put the name of the project, name of the university I want to have it on the first slide

Comment: @x-rw You are probably looking for `\maketitle`? Should it have the headline or not?

Comment: yes   should, you can edit your answer by adding that part please

Comment: @x-rw Please see my edited answer

Comment: i edited my question, 
the header should only exist in the new section

Comment: before placing the first page I think I did not have this problem (I add a new image that describes the problem)

Comment: @x-rw ??? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say

Comment: i compile again and it's all OK