# How to put the logo on the upper left side?

Tags: beamer

How to put the logo of my university on the upper left side?, 
I do not want to have the logo on the right side

`example-image-a` i should change to direcction of my logo university?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\def\insertlogoright{\usebeamertemplate*{logoright}}
\def\logoright{\setbeamertemplate{logoright}}

\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mycustom theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
        \hfill%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogoright}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}


\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

{
 \setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{logoright}{}
 \begin{frame}
  \maketitle
 \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

i want this result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default headline instead of your customisation, the logo will be at the top left by default.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and if I want to put it on the right side, how would it be?

Comment: i use this  \logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{vw2.png}} but i get error

Comment: @x-rw But your question asked how to put the logo on the left? I'm really confused what you are asking??? If you want them on the right site, use the code from your question.

Comment: I'm following your answer to my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458357/only-the-slide-of-a-new-section-to-have-a-header  
and I want to put two logos (left and right) on the first page

Comment: to not confuse better start another question?