# Is it possible to put a picture on the header of a slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to put a logo on the top right of the headers of all my slides (c.f. the following picture) but I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Can someone help me about it please.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put the logo on the upper left side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458420/how-to-put-the-logo-on-the-upper-left-side)

Comment: Not really. It works with the Berkeley theme, but it doesnt works with my curent theme (Madrid).

Comment: Please include a small, but compilable test document in your question so that one does not need to guess the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack (you will make sure that your title is short enough to not be hidden by the logo):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\usepackage{tikz}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much

Comment: @AdrienVaret You're welcome!