# Put 2 logos (left and right)

Tags: beamer

I want to put 2 logos (left and right) only on the first page, 
and if you can also on the last page

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx} 
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Title]{title} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page


\institute[UMSS] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{U} \\
\textit{Fac} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\textit{autor} % Your name
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date
\newlength\imageheight
%\settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics[width=0.11\paperwidth]{vw.png}}
\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}
  {%
    \ifnum\thepage=\insertsectionstartpage
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
       \logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
       \logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}

        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}    
    \fi
  }
%\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
%\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
%\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}



\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

but this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous question you had logos on both sites but explicitly removed them for the title page. If you want them only on your title page, do it the other way round:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\def\insertlogoright{\usebeamertemplate*{logoright}}
\def\logoright{\setbeamertemplate{logoright}}

\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mycustom theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
        \hfill%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogoright}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}


\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

%{
% \setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
% \setbeamertemplate{logoright}{}
 \begin{frame}
  \maketitle
 \end{frame}
%}

\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
\setbeamertemplate{logoright}{}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you'd like to combine this with the modified headline from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458358/36296 you could introduce a different headline after the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\def\insertlogoright{\usebeamertemplate*{logoright}}
\def\logoright{\setbeamertemplate{logoright}}

\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mycustom theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
        \hfill%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{%
        \hss%
        \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogoright}\vss%
        }%
        \hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}


\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

%{
% \setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
% \setbeamertemplate{logoright}{}
 \begin{frame}
  \maketitle
 \end{frame}
%}

\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
\setbeamertemplate{logoright}{}


\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}
  {%
    \ifnum\thepage=\insertsectionstartpage
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}    
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\section{title}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{this}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: modify your answer with my example that I put in this question please

Comment: @x-rw The example from your question does not compile and I also don't have the necessary images

Comment: i edited my question with example-image-a

Comment: @x-rw Still does not compile, undefined control sequence.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5bdf11657a791028b22d25ce there is my code

Comment: @x-rw "Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page."

Comment: @x-rw And just because overleaf is exceptionally good at hiding crucial information like error messages does not that there is no error. You need to define `\logoright`, this is a custom command which does not work by default. You can look up the definition in your previous question.

Comment: but is your answer of this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458357/only-the-slide-of-a-new-section-to-have-a-header

Comment: @x-rw It is similar to my answer (for which you don't give any attribution in your question), but I'm not using `logoright` !

Comment: one more question please, how can I put the logos in the end too?

Comment: @x-rw I'm again confused. You write in your question "only on the first page" and now you want them somewhere else? I explicitly switched them off after the title page.

Comment: Could it be, or is the change too much? I try to modify the if but I do not manage to affect the first and last page

Comment: @x-rw Place `\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\logoright{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[mycustom theme]` before your last frame to switch back to the two-logo headline